# Filter a datatable based on another datatable

Tags: r, filter, data.table

I have the following `data.table`s

```
library(data.table)


 dt_1 <- data.table(id = c('cg','fs','fs'),
                 v1 = c('a','a','b'),
                 v2 = c('d','e','f'))

dt_2 <- data.table(id = c('cg','fs','cg'),
                   v1 = c('a','a','b'))
```

And I would like to filter `dt_1` based on `dt_2`. In the end I would like to end up with

```
   id v1 v2
1: fs  b  f
```

So filter out the **exact** rows of `dt_1` that are contained in `dt_2`

This operation

```
dt_1[!(id%in%dt_2$id & v1%in%dt_2$v1)]
```

Does not work because it takes also the inner combinations of `dt_2$id` and `dt_2$v1` and this

`dt_1[!dt_2]` throws an error.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify on what you're joining:

```
dt_1[!dt_2, on=names(dt_2)] # "easier" than intersect(names(dt_1), names(dt_2)) because all dt_2 variables are in dt_1 but in a more general context the latter will be preferable
#   id v1 v2
#1: fs  b  f
```

Answer (score 4):

We could use `anti_join`

```
library(dplyr)
anti_join(dt_1, dt_2)
#  id v1 v2
#1 fs  b  f
```

---

Note that if the column names are the same, we could use `data.table::fsetdiff`

```
fsetdiff(dt_1, dt_2)
```